# I cannot get this sql query to take my distances and put into categories in case statement

Tags: sql

I have a sql query that is taking the latitude and longitude from the table and comparing it to the set latitiude and longitude from my location. I want to be able to have a case statement that will break down the miles into my other columns.

*Here I am taking the latitude and longitude from the people and finding distance from a set point and making it into a field called Miles

```
Select
(
3959 * acos (
cos ( radians(43.7779) )
* cos( radians( fc.Address1_Latitude ) )
* cos( radians( fc.Address1_Longitude ) - radians(-88.4215) )
+ sin ( radians(43.7779) )
* sin( radians( fc.Address1_Latitude ) )
 ))
 As Miles
 from filteredcontact fc
```

**Here is where the problem is, I am trying to take the miles I found and trying to put it into the categories in the next case statements. So for example, anybody who is 0-24 miles from campus I want it to put how many inquires, applicants, confirmed etc. I want to do this for each set of distances.

```
 select case
 WHEN 'Miles' < 25   THEN '0-24'
 WHEN 'Miles' <= 25 and 'Miles' <49 THEN '25-49'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 50 and 'Miles' < 74 THEN '50-74'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 75 and 'Miles' < 99 THEN '75-99'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 100 and 'Miles' < 125 THEN '100-125'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 126 and 'Miles' < 151 THEN '126-151'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 152 and 'Miles' < 177 THEN '152-177'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 178 and 'Miles' < 203 THEN '178-203'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 204 and 'Miles' < 229 THEN '204-229'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 230 and 'Miles' < 255 THEN '230-255'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 256 and 'Miles' < 281 THEN '256-281'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 282 and 'Miles' < 307 THEN '282-307'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 308 and 'Miles' < 333 THEN '308-333'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 334 and 'Miles' < 359 THEN '334-359'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 360 and 'Miles' < 385 THEN '360-385'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 386 and 'Miles' < 411 THEN '386-411'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 412 and 'Miles' < 437 THEN '412-437'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 438 and 'Miles' < 463 THEN '438-463'
  WHEN 'Miles' >= 464 and 'Miles' < 489 THEN '464-489'
 WHEN 'Miles' >= 490 and 'Miles' < 500 THEN '490-500'
 ELSE 'over 500'
 END
```

**Here is where it takes and puts the miles above into columns.

```
  sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Prospect','Inquiry', 'Applicant', 'Admit',
 'Confirmed', 'Enrolled', 'Application Started', 'Application Submitted',
 'Application Completed', 'Application Moved to ERP') then 1 else NULL End) as "INQ",
  sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Applicant','Admit', 'Confirmed', 'Enrolled',
    'Application Submitted', 'Application Completed',
  'Application Moved to ERP')then 1 else NULL End) as "APP",
   (select cast (sum(case when  fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in          ('Applicant','Admit', 'Confirmed',
 'Enrolled', 'Application Submitted', 'Application Completed',
 'Application Moved to ERP') then 1 else NULL End)as float)/
 (sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Prospect','Inquiry', 'Applicant', 'Admit',
 'Confirmed', 'Enrolled', 'Application Started', 'Application Submitted',
 'Application Completed', 'Application Moved to ERP') then 1 else NULL End))) "APP/INQ",
  sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Admit', 'Confirmed',
   'Enrolled') then 1 else NULL End) as "ADM",
    (select cast (sum(case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Admit', 'Confirmed',
    'Enrolled') then 1 else NULL End)as float)/
   (sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in  ('Applicant','Admit', 'Confirmed', 'Enrolled',
    'Application Submitted', 'Application Completed',
  'Application Moved to ERP') then 1 else NULL End))) "ADM/APP",
     sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Confirmed', 'Enrolled') then 1 else NULL End) as "DEP",
   (select cast (sum(case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Confirmed', 'Enrolled') then 1 else NULL End)as float)/
   (sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Admit', 'Confirmed',
    'Enrolled') then 1 else NULL End))) "DEP/ADM",
    sum (case when fc.elucnsrv_currentprimaryappstatusname Like '%Canceled%' then 1 else NULL       End) as "CAN",
    (select cast (sum(case when fc.elucnsrv_currentprimaryappstatusname Like '%Canceled%' then 1 else NULL End)as float)/
   (sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Confirmed', 'Enrolled') then 1 else NULL End))) "CAN/DEP"
   sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname ='Enrolled' then 1 else NULL end) as "ENR",
  (select cast (sum(case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname ='Enrolled' then 1 else NULL End)as float)/
  (sum (case when fc.datatel_prospectstatusname in ('Admit', 'Confirmed', 'Enrolled') then 1 else NULL End))) "ENR/ADM"




FROM  FilteredContact fc
  where fc.Address1_Latitude is not null
  and fc.Address1_Longitude is not null
  and fc.FirstName is not null
 and fc.LastName is not null
 and fc.datatel_academiclevelofinterestidname in ('PreProfessional' , 'Undergraduate' , 'Special')
  and (fc.statecodename = 'Active' and fc.customertypecodename = 'Prospective Student')
  group by fc.address1_latitude, fc.address1_longitude
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you want your output to look like? A simple typed-in matrix of your desired results with 2-3 example rows would help people understand your question.

Comment: Is the problem in that `Case` Statement? Because it is comparing the `String` 'Miles' with an `int`, and it will always be false.

Comment: Look below at the printscreen

Answer (score 0):

[image]Not sure what exactly the issue is here, but I noticed a few things:

1. In your 2nd code block, you have:

   ```
   select case
   WHEN 'Miles' < 25   THEN '0-24'
   WHEN 'Miles' **<=** 25 and 'Miles' <49 THEN '25-49'
   ...
   ```

   and it looks like this should be

   ```
   select case
   WHEN 'Miles' < 25   THEN '0-24'
   WHEN 'Miles' **>=** 25 and 'Miles' <49 THEN '25-49'
   ...
   ```
2. In your 2nd code block, the compiler will see and evaluate 'Miles' as a string literal, rather than as a pointer to a column (which appears to be the intended behavior).  This will cause a conversion error

Also, are you getting any errors (i.e. not compiling), or is the data just incorrect?  If the data is incorrect, things like how you know it is incorrect or how you know the data is wrong will help us.

One thing you could do (it ain't pretty) is something like this:

```
    declare @MilesTable TABLE (Miles INT)
    INSERT INTO @MilesTable (Miles)
    Select
    (
    3959 * acos (
    cos ( radians(43.7779) )
    * cos( radians( fc.Address1_Latitude ) )
    * cos( radians( fc.Address1_Longitude ) - radians(-88.4215) )
    + sin ( radians(43.7779) )
    * sin( radians( fc.Address1_Latitude ) )
     ))
     from filteredcontact fc

     select case
     WHEN Miles < 25   THEN '0-24'
     WHEN Miles <= 25 and 'Miles' <49 THEN '25-49'
     WHEN Miles >= 50 and 'Miles' < 74 THEN '50-74'
     WHEN Miles >= 75 and 'Miles' < 99 THEN '75-99'
     WHEN Miles >= 100 and 'Miles' < 125 THEN '100-125'
     WHEN Miles >= 126 and 'Miles' < 151 THEN '126-151'
     WHEN Miles >= 152 and 'Miles' < 177 THEN '152-177'
     WHEN Miles >= 178 and 'Miles' < 203 THEN '178-203'
     WHEN Miles >= 204 and 'Miles' < 229 THEN '204-229'
     WHEN Miles >= 230 and 'Miles' < 255 THEN '230-255'
     WHEN Miles >= 256 and 'Miles' < 281 THEN '256-281'
     WHEN Miles >= 282 and 'Miles' < 307 THEN '282-307'
     WHEN Miles >= 308 and 'Miles' < 333 THEN '308-333'
     WHEN Miles >= 334 and 'Miles' < 359 THEN '334-359'
     WHEN Miles >= 360 and 'Miles' < 385 THEN '360-385'
     WHEN Miles >= 386 and 'Miles' < 411 THEN '386-411'
     WHEN Miles >= 412 and 'Miles' < 437 THEN '412-437'
     WHEN Miles >= 438 and 'Miles' < 463 THEN '438-463'
      WHEN Miles >= 464 and 'Miles' < 489 THEN '464-489'
     WHEN Miles >= 490 and 'Miles' < 500 THEN '490-500'
     ELSE 'over 500'
     END
     FROM @MilesTable
```

Like I said, it's not pretty but it will alleviate the conversion errors at a minimum....hope this gets you started in the right direction!

Comment: But the thing is we are not using a miles table, this is a column we are putting into the report. We have it down to where we can get the distance from campus without using this select statement. After it converts the miles, we then want it to put the numbers into the coluhms. So for example I would live 20 miles away from campus after the math. Now I want to put my milage into a category, which I would fall under the applied category and under 24 miles from campus. We are trying to get cumulative totals for each category.

Comment: I think what you'd have to do then is to put the:
(
    3959 * acos (
    cos ( radians(43.7779) )
    * cos( radians( fc.Address1_Latitude ) )
    * cos( radians( fc.Address1_Longitude ) - radians(-88.4215) )
    + sin ( radians(43.7779) )
    * sin( radians( fc.Address1_Latitude ) )
     ))
after your WHEN.  If you're trying to run a case statement against a column that you are creating at runtime, it won't work the way it is written in the original post because while you and I know that the column is called 'Miles', SQL doesn't know that.  It would be huge and nasty, hence @MilesTable